# error when postgres use copy to insert a CSV with a field timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, csv, copy

I followed the instructions that are commented in the documentation of postgres to create the logs as CSV format, and then create a table in the database with the corresponding fields (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG)

The content of the CSV look like following:

```
2013-11-07 23:07:31.524 CET,"postgres","postgres",5556,"::1:62188",527c0f1e.15b4,1,"idle",2013-11-07 23:07:26 CET,2/23,0,LOG,00000,"sentencia: DROP TABLE public.mytable",,,,,,,,,"pgAdmin III - Browser"
```

But when I execute the COPY instruction:

```
COPY postgres_log FROM '/full/path/to/logfile.csv' WITH csv;
```

An error is occurs, saying that syntax of the type timestamp with time zone is not valid:

```
ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo timestamp with time zone: «﻿2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET»
CONTEXT:  COPY postgreslog, línea 1, columna log_time: «﻿2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET»
********** Error **********
ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo timestamp with time zone: «﻿2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET»
SQL state: 22007
Context: COPY postgreslog, línea 1, columna log_time: «﻿2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET»
```

If I insert directly a registry using for instance PgAdminIII, and I set as value of 'log_time' column '2013-11-07 23:07:31.524 CET', it is inserted correctly.

Anybody knows what's happening?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works: insert into postgreslog (log_time, session_id, session_line_num) values('2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET', 'a', 1);

Comment: How is your table created?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it works or not I think you should probably preprocess your timestamp to use explicit offsets as the timezone first.  I see a number of unpleasant surprises when I try this timezone on my system.

```
foo=# select '2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET'::timestamp;

        timestamp        
-------------------------
 2013-11-07 23:04:59.124
(1 row)
```

That is expected but

```
foo=# select '2013-11-07 23:04:59.124 CET'::timestamptz;

        timestamptz         
----------------------------
 2013-11-07 14:04:59.124-08
(1 row)
```

That is the wrong timezone.

So this is not going to do what you want it to do.  This seems that the timezone is ignored under both ISO and Postgres date styles.  Get rid of it and change to a fixed offset or remove the timestamp from the field.  But either way get rid of the CET as it is not doing what you want.

It looks like there may be parsing issues here.  Now that I have identified one, I am not sure I would trust there not to be more.